# .htaccess make root website show as sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm running my project with this command: `php -S locahost:8080`, and I would like to change URL behavior like this:

`localhost:8080/books --> localhost:800/subfolder/books/`

And the request should be mapped to the `index.php` file in the root folder.

It would help me a lot!

Comment: If you are using php's buildin test server your setup has nothing to do with Apache's distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those are only available and therefore relevant when you use the apache http server to serve your project.